# Telerik report table data are not set in proper way

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, report, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

I am using telerik report table for report generation

I have issue regarding data are not set on page side by side , It will kept some space and start data printing from new pages , accepted result is that in report data will be print side by side , there is not allow any kind of white space in between report

How can I achieve that in telerik report,

here by I attached screenshot of that issue

[image]

Please let me know , I am not able to find any way for set data in linear way without putting any space between pages

Thanks !!!!

Comment: Do you check all margins in page and the report section?

Comment: Do you check all margins in page and the report section?Your end margins and your report footer is very effective.Sum of these spaces plus height of every row could create this issue.It is probably variable in various pages , some pages have less or more of the gaps

Answer (score 0):

In the table property, make "KeepTogether : False" in the Behavior section.